# Defining closed and open sets with quantifiers.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm taking an intro to analysis course, and, given the following definitions of closed and open sets, I was wondering whether my attempt at quantifying them is correct.

> *Definition* A set $A\subset R$ is closed iff every accumulation point of $A$ belongs to $A$  $$\overset{{?}}{\iff}\forall{x}\left(\forall\varepsilon>0\exists{a\in{N(x,\varepsilon)\cap (A\setminus{\{x\})}}}\implies x\in{A}\right)$$
>
> A set $E\subset R$ is open iff for every $x\in A$ there is a neighborhood  $N(x,\varepsilon)$ of $x$ such that $N\subset A$ $$\overset{{?}}{\iff}\forall{x}\in{A}\exists\varepsilon>0:N(x,\varepsilon)\subset{A}$$

Comment: How do you define $N(x,\varepsilon)$?

Comment: @José Carlos Santos it’s an intro class so we’re only in $\mathbb{R}^1$. We’re defining an $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of $x$ in a set $A$ such that $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\subset{A}$.

Comment: Comment (not an answer) You do need to learn to read and write these statements with explicit quantifiers but for understanding (both reading and writing) it's better to rely on the mostly English text.

Comment: Before the '$\in a$', you have to introduce $N(x,\epsilon)$. And instead of $N(x, \epsilon)$, I would write $B(x,\epsilon)$, which is the open ball around $x$.

Answer (score -1):

Let $A\subset \mathbb R $.

$A $ is colsed in $\color {red}{\mathbb R} \iff $

$$\overline {A}\subset A \iff $$

$$(\forall x\in \color {red}{\mathbb R}) $$

$$\Bigl ( \forall \epsilon>0 \; (x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\cap A \neq \emptyset \implies x\in A\Bigr) $$

Comment: Downvote ununderstood.

Comment: I did not downvote

Comment: @AlexD It is surely a supertramp elector.